# How would I extract year from a date when using the case when command

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a code to document if an appointment occured from January 1 to August 31st then it would return the year of the appointment and if it was from September 1st to December 31st, it would be the year of the appointment + 1. The date is set like: 1-JAN-2022.

This is the line i'm trying to use. I'm not that good with SQl but is this the way I'm supposed to be extracting the year or would I have to make it in another part of the code?

```
case when "AppointmentDate" BETWEEN '1-SEP' AND '31-DEC' then EXTRACT(YEAR from "AppointmentDate" + 1) else (YEAR FROM "AppointmentDate") END "Years",
```

Thanks for any advice or criticism in advance.

Comment: Just as an aside, it appears you are enclosing your column names in double-quotes.  This is poor practice in oracle, as it _forces_ case-sensitivity.  In oracle, we prefer the default case-INsensitive behavior of NOT enclosing names in double-quotes.  In order to make multi-word names more readable, we use underscore instead of mixed case.  So your column would be APPOINTMENT_DATE, and you could actually write it in any case - 'APPOINTMENT_DATE', or 'appointment_date', or 'Appointment_Date'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on `AppointmentDate` column's datatype; looks like it is `date` (according to `extract` function you use). If that's so, then it further depends on database you use. Is it Oracle? Perhaps, as you use Oracle SQL Developer.

If so, you'd have to "extract" month and day out of column's value, but not the way you did it; strings are *tricky* to be compared if you don't know what you're doing.

I'm not saying that this is the *best* option, but - it might work: using the `to_char` function, extract month and day (`mmdd` format mask). Note that `between` is *inclusive*, it'll take both boundaries. Maybe you'd rather use `between '0101' and '0831'`.

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN TO_CHAR ("AppointmentDate", 'mmdd') BETWEEN '0101' AND '0901'
          THEN
             EXTRACT (YEAR FROM "AppointmentDate") + 1
          ELSE
             EXTRACT (YEAR FROM "AppointmentDate")
       END "Years"
  FROM your_table
```

Comment: TO_CHAR - in this example - "converts" DATE datatype value into a string whose format is MMDD (two digits for month and two digits for day). For example, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE), 'MMDD') returns 0810 (because today is August 10th.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for your help. The query is taking forever to load but I think this is what I needed. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can add four months and dispense with the `case` altogether:

```
extract(year from add_months(appointment_date, 4)) as the_year
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this query that well I'm sorry. How does it tell the query that all the dates between January 1 and August 31 to return the year value and after those dates to return the year +1?

Comment: @MaxMani . . . Because if you add four months you are in the next year, for dates starting on Sep 1.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll keep that in mind next time. Thank you for the insight as well.