# How to get an Extract date or time as a return value in a case statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want an extracted time (or date) as a return value from a case statement.

I'm trying to do this using Google BigQuery:

```
    SELECT 
    
    case 
        when OrderEvent ="created" 
        then
          extract(time from OrderCreated_dttm)
        ELSE
          “Order not started” 
        end as order_created_time
    
    FROM `my_table`
```

But I got this error message:
Could not cast literal "order not started" to type TIME at [11:7]

What's wrong?
There is no problem to extract the time doing like this:

```
  SELECT
     extract(time from OrderCreated_dttm) as Created_time
    FROM `my_table`
```

I think this question is similar, but didn't helped me:
[How would I extract year from a date when using the case when command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726787/how-would-i-extract-year-from-a-date-when-using-the-case-when-command/76926908#76926908)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the expected output is either **a TIME** (an extracted time value; extract(time from OrderCreated_dttm)) or **a String** ("Order not started") type, you have to format the time as a string **to make each record to have the same column type**.

You may want to use [FORMAT_DATETIME()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime) as below.

*(You are not allowed to have one record of colum1 to be TIME type and the other record to be string type)*

###### Query

```sql
WITH
my_dataset AS (
    SELECT 'created' AS OrderEvent, DATETIME('2023-08-18T07:30:00') AS OrderCreated_dttm,
    UNION ALL SELECT 'not created' AS OrderEvent, DATETIME('2023-08-18T08:30:00') AS OrderCreated_dttm,
)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN OrderEvent = 'created' THEN FORMAT_DATETIME("%H:%M:%S", OrderCreated_dttm)
        ELSE "Order not started"
    END AS order_created_time,
FROM my_dataset
;
```

###### Results

[image]